# Compute of variation

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

How to compute the equality 2 ? I think it's to use normal coordinate,then $\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$, then $\nabla_h\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$, then $R_{ijk}^h=0$. Whether I am right ?

$\delta$ is variation, $\partial_tg_{ij}=-2R_{ij}$ .

Below picture is from 200th page of [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947)

> [image]